# javascript multiple OR conditions in IF statement

Tags: javascript

I think I'm missing something basic here. Why is the third IF condition true? Shouldn't the condition evaluate to false? I want to do something where the id is not 1, 2 or 3.

```
var id = 1;
if(id == 1) //true    
if(id != 1) //false 
if(id != 1 || id != 2 || id != 3) //this returns true. why?
```

Thank you.

Comment: because `id` does not equal `2` or `3`? `false || true || true == true`

Comment: 1 != 2 .. this is obviously true.. lollzzz

Comment: Then it should return `false`, I think? Sorry, I've been working all night so not able to think clearly.

Comment: [Or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) vs [And](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)

Comment: @dku.rajkumar the `var i = 1` was just an example. I need to do work on some 50 ids but skip where id is 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @user349308: If *any* of the conditions are `true`, it will return `true`. Remeber that `!=` means *does NOT equal*, so `1 != 2` is a `true` statement, so it returns `true`.

Comment: @user349308: *"skip where id is 1, 2, or 3."*, Then do `if(!(id==1 || id==2 || id==3))` or `if(id!=1 && id!=2 && id!=3)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With an `OR` (||) operation, if any one of the conditions are true, the result is true.

I think you want an `AND` (&&) operation here.

Comment: Thank you. Now I feel stupid for asking this question :( I got confused.

Comment: Ha. We've all been there, trust me.

Comment: @Gabe Okay I have a question, how I know which condition is matched?

Comment: @SachinfromPune I think you are looking for a switch statement...https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 28):

You want to execute code where the id is not (1 or 2 or 3), but the OR operator does not distribute over id.  The only way to say what you want is to say

> the id is not 1, and the id is not 2, and the id is not 3.

which translates to

```
if (id !== 1 && id !== 2 && id !== 3)
```

or alternatively for something more pythonesque:

```
if (!(id in [,1,2,3]))
```

Comment: The alternative checks for the index. Not if the value is in the array. Unlike in python where it checks for the value.

`array.indexOf(id) == -1` means that the id isn't in the array. use `!=` for the opposite.

Comment: @NeilDesh, note the `,` at the start.  They're equivalent

Comment: @MikeSamuel Then why is `4 in [,4,2,3]` false

Comment: @NeilDesh, the trick is to have a partial identity mapping.  It only works for small counting numbers so it's not generally useful.  To represent the set (4) try `[,,,,4]`.

Comment: This answer is misleading as it checks the index not the value of the array. The correct way is to use `Array.includes(value)`.

Comment: @denisb411 The partial identity array maintains an equivalence between key and value.  You're right about `.includes`, but there was no such thing when I wrote that in 2012.  Happy to accept an edit or up-vote a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the three conditions is evaluated independently[1]:

```
id != 1 // false
id != 2 // true
id != 3 // true
```

Then it evaluates `false || true || true`, which is true (`a || b` is true if either `a` or `b` is true). I think you want

```
id != 1 && id != 2 && id != 3
```

which is only true if the ID is not 1 AND it's not 2 AND it's not 3.

[1]: This is not strictly true, look up [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In reality, only the first two clauses are evaluated because that is all that is necessary to determine the truth value of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

When it checks id!=2 it returns true and stops further checking

Comment: This is important to note too; it comes in handy if you need to see if an object exists before checking a parameter. `if(obj != null && obj.field == 2)`

Answer (score 1):

because the OR operator will return true if any one of the conditions is true, and in your code there are two conditions that are true.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
false && true || true   // returns true
false && (true || true) // returns false
(true || true || true)  // returns true
false || true           // returns true
true || false           // returns true
```